# Cannot not get listview item id in another activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

When `listview` item is tapped it should send the **item id** to the another activity.

My is as follows, it shows an error at

```
Cursor cursor = trDb.getReminder(value);
```

and the error is

```
Incompatible type.
    Required: android.database.Cursor;
    Found:    com.android.app.TRListFormat
```

code snippet of `TRList.class`

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tbr_list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TRList.this, TRTimeReminder.class);
            intent.putExtra("remId", (int)id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

code snippet of `TRTimeReminder.class`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        int value = extras.getInt("remId");
        if(value > 0){
            Cursor cursor = trDb.getReminder(value);  //this line is red showing the error I have written above
            id_To_Update = value;
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRDBHelper.COLUMN_TITLE));
            String des = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRDBHelper.COLUMN_DES));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRDBHelper.COLUMN_DATE));
            String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRDBHelper.COLUMN_TIME));
            if (!cursor.isClosed()) cursor.close();

            edTitle.setText(title);
            edDes.setText(des);
            dateView.setText(date);
            timeView.setText(time);
        }
    }
```

`getReminder` method of `TRDBHelper.class`

```
TRListFormat getReminder(int id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_DES,
                            COLUMN_DATE, COLUMN_TIME}, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return new TRListFormat(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
}
```

Comment: Can you post method `getReminder()`?

Comment: I have edited my question, please check @skywall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

> TRListFormat getReminder(int id)

`getReminder` return type is `TRListFormat` but you are trying to assign `TRListFormat` class object to `Cursor` object:

```
TRListFormat objTRListFormat = trDb.getReminder(value);
```

Comment: Now it shows new errors at getting title, des, date, time. I replaced `Cursor` object with `TRListFormat` object but it is not compatible to get title, des, date, time values from database.

Comment: @Apurva: you need to access title,des... using `objTRListFormat` object as objTRListFormat.title,objTRListFormat.des,...

Comment: @Apurva: makr sure `title,des,...` all required variables are public in TRListFormat class or you can also create getter methods in `TRListFormat` class to access values